Find a winning strategy for a simple betting game
I heard the following simple betting game in a conference presentation by a stock trader and tried thinking about the winning strategy, but the more I think about it the more confused I get.
The game is as follows. Two players take turns betting higher amounts until one of them stops, at which point the player who bet the most wins $100. However, both players lose the final amount they bet. The goal is to find a strategy which makes the most money.
I believe an optimal strategy will be some sort of mixed strategy similar to poker.
Some possible strategies:

Always bet one cent higher than the other player. However if the other player adopts this strategy as well, your expected loses are infinite.

Always bet one cent higher than the other player until you reach $100. However the other player might adopt the strategy to always bet one cent higher until they reach 101.01, in which case you'd lose 100 and the other player would lose 1 cent.

Bet 99.99 on turn one before the opponent has bet. This way the opponent has no reason to bet, since they may win 100, but they will lose the 100 they bet netting them 0 overall. This strategy apparently makes 1 penny, but is there a better strategy?

Suppose there is an optimal strategy which makes on average X dollars per round. In this case betting above X dollars apparently loses money, since you pay more than your expected winnings, but there is reason to bet above X dollars. This is because if you don't and the opponent realizes your strategy, they will begin betting X+1 dollars.


I'd certainly appreciate help understanding this game, since it seems very fascinating being so simple yet so confusing. It seems significantly simpler than poker so I'd hope since poker seems fairly well understood with computers, this game could also be understood.

What do you mean by "take turns betting"?   If it's an auction repeating bets until someone stops, then it's not a "clearly" that a bet will not exceed $100.  This is known as a war of attrition.

I agree with @user10478.  The posted question becomes trivial if each person knows the other's bid(s).  That is, each person should then always bid $~$99.99.$  I suspect your intent is that each player make one sealed bid, at which point your analysis makes sense and the question becomes much more interesting.  If you agree, then I suggest that you edit your posted question accordingly.

Alternatively, you could have $~k~$ rounds of bidding, where in each round, both players submit sealed bids.  At the end of that round, both sealed bids are opened and shown to both players.  Then, the next round of bidding begins.  In this alternative form of the question, you would need an added constraint, such as:  Each person's next (sealed) bid must be between $~$15~$ and $~$30~$ greater than their previous sealed bid.

You're describing an all-pay sealed bid(?) auction, for which the symmetric Nash equilibrium can be derived through calculus.  $\quad$ @user2661923 I don't see why we must have an added constraint. Players are still allowed to bid whatever they want.

@CalvinLin I am inexperienced in this area.  Suppose that you set $~k = 5,~$ (i.e. 5 rounds of bidding), adopt the [sealed-bid : Nash equilibrium] environment, but without any added constraint.  Aren't the first $~4~$ rounds of bidding pointless?  That is, on the last round, the bidder is free to bid what they want, without any consideration of the previous bidding rounds.  So, absent any additional constraints (e.g. the $~+ $15 ~:: ~+ $30 ~$ constraint), the $~5~$ bidding round scenario is equivalent to only having $~1~$ bidding round.  What am I missing?

@user2661923 I think you're interpreting it as 5 consecutive bids for a single prize. $\quad$ That's not my interpretation. There are 5 prizes to be won. Each bid is submitted for a single prize. Or you can think of it as 5 distinct auctions happening at the same time.

@CalvinLin I agree with your interpretation of the original problem.  The point that I was making was that if you are going to alter the problem so that there are (for example) $~5~$ rounds of bidding before the single prize is awarded, such an alternation is meaningless without an added constraint.  That is, without the added constraint, the first 4 rounds become pointless.  With the added constraint, or a similar added constraint, the result seems to be a more complicated math problem to attack.

@user2661923 I do not understand how the question is trivial if each person knows the other persons bids. Betting 99.99 might make 1 penny per round, but is that really the best strategy? How do you know there is not a strategy which makes more than 1 penny per round?

@StephenHarrison The two players take turns betting higher amounts.  Assume that collusion is prevented, so that you can not arrange for me to bet 0.00 so that you can bet 0.01.   If my first bet is always 99.99, exactly what strategy will you employ, as the 2nd bettor, to maximize your profit?  Will you decline to bet?  If you are the first bettor, will you bet 99.99?  If you do, then should I bet 100.00, or should I decline to bet?
